# Swift audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying method not called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudioplayer

I created the three UIButtons on the MainStoryBoard.

When I press "yourButton3", player3 is not called.

I found that changing the else if the clause or assigning something to player3 would solve this problem, but do not know how.

```
       override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            player1?.delegate = self
            player2?.delegate = self
            player3?.delegate = self
        }

        let url1 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music1.mp3")
        let url2 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music2.mp3")

        @IBOutlet weak var yourButton: customButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var yourButton2: customButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var yourButton3: customButton!


        fileprivate var player1:AVAudioPlayer?
        fileprivate var player2:AVAudioPlayer?
        fileprivate var player3:AVAudioPlayer?


        @IBAction func pushButton1(sender: UIButton) {
            Player(url: url1)
        }

        @IBAction func pushButton2(sender: UIButton) {
            Player1(url: url2)
        }

        @IBAction func pushButton3(_ sender: UIButton) {
            Player(url: url2)
            player1!.play()

        }

//player3 is not called in this code

        func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
            if (player === player1) {
                yourButton.isSelected = false
            } else if (player === player2) {
                yourButton2.isSelected = false
            } else if (player === player3) {
                yourButton.isSelected = false
                player2!.play()
                yourButton2.isSelected = false
            }
        }



        func Player(url: URL) {
            do {
                try player1 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)
                player1!.play()
                yourButton.isSelected = true
                player1!.delegate = self
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        func Player1(url: URL) {
            do {
                try player2 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)
                player2!.play()
                yourButton2.isSelected = true
                player2!.delegate = self

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        func Player3(url: URL, url2: URL) {
            do {
                try player1 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)
                try player2 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url2)
                player1!.play()
                yourButton.isSelected = true
                player1!.delegate = self
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't init player3 in your `Player(url:)` function, so `player === player3` will never be true.

You can edit your `Player3(url:, url2:)` function as below:

```
func Player3(url: URL, url2: URL) {
    do {
        try player3 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)
        try player2 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url2)
        player3!.play()
        yourButton.isSelected = true
        player3!.delegate = self
        player2!.delegate = self
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

and call it like that:

```
@IBAction func pushButton3(_ sender: UIButton) {
    Player3(url: url1, url2: url2)
}
```

Comment: If you could help me with following question it would be nice!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271453/how-to-multiple-play-in-audioplayerdidfinishplaying-method